# System.BadImageFormatException when running C# program

Tags: c#, .net

I'm compiling a C# program on VS 2010 on Windows 7, then running the files (all taken from the build's bin\Debug directory) on another 32-bit machine.

The files from the Debug directory also contain the Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Library.dll file that this program relies on.

On the VS 2010 project's build configuration, the platform is set to x86. Yet on the 32-bit machine it results in a System.BadImageFormatException.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 
'Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Library, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to 
contain an assembly manifest. File name: 'Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Library, 
Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'
```

What can the reason for this be?

Comment: Are there other dependencies (perhaps installed in the GAC) available on the development machine but not on the deployed machine?

Comment: Other than System.* references, there is only the Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Library entry under the VS Studio project's "References" section

Comment: Right, but there could be dependencies upon dependencies. I have a couple of (somewhat) large projects that use DLLs I've created in other projects. These DLLs depend upon other DLLs themselves, but there's no indication that those dependencies exist in the References section (because the "new" project only sees the immediate dependency, not "sub" dependencies). You may need to install (reinstall?) Project Server on the target machine for this to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I still think it's a x86 v x64 issue. Does the executable depend on other x64 libraries?

Comment: Ah, even though I changed the build settings to x86, I still copied the old files from bin\Debug instead of the bin\x86\Debug directory

Comment: I've never seeen BadImageFormatException mean anything but x32 vs x64.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that the problem machine's .NET framework is not up to the same version as the build machine.

Comment: Compiling machine has .NET framework 4.0. The target machine has .NET framework versions 2.0 3.0 and 3.5. Let me get 4.0 on there